# Take the current admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

serializers.py

```
class RegSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    admin = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='username', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Registration
        fields = [
        'id', 'rooms', 'first_name', 'last_name','admin', 'pasport_serial_num', 'birth_date', 'img', 'visit_date',
        'leave_date', 'guest_count', 'room_bool']
```

models.py

```
class Rooms(models.Model):
    objects = None
    room_num = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Комната')
    room_bool = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Релевантность')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Категория')
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Цена (сум)', null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.room_num}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Комнату'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Комнаты'


class Registration(models.Model):
    objects = None
    rooms = models.ForeignKey(Rooms, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Номер',
                              help_text='Номер в который хотите заселить гостя!',
                         )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Имя')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Администратор')
    pasport_serial_num = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Серия паспорта', help_text='*AB-0123456')
    birth_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата рождения')
    img = models.FileField(verbose_name='Фото документа', help_text='Загружайте файл в формате .pdf')
    visit_date = models.DateField(
        default=django.utils.timezone.localdate, verbose_name='Дата прибытия')
    leave_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Дата отбытия', default='После ухода!')
    guest_count = models.IntegerField(default=1, verbose_name='Кол-во людей')
    room_bool = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Релевантность',
                                    help_text='При бронирование отключите галочку')
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Цена (сум)', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.rooms},{self.last_name},{self.first_name},{self.room_bool}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Номер'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Регистрация'
```

how can I make it so that the name of the user who registered room is indicated in the admin field and without the right to change only readonly?

can this be done at all?
thanks in advance for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass [additional attributes](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save) to serilizer's save method. In your view, you can call serializer save() with `admin` argument like this:

```
def your_view(request):
    # your code
    serializer.save(admin=request.user)
```

Or if you want to do it on admin page, you can override your admin's [`save_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method. Also you should specify `admin` as a [readonly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields):

```
class RegistrationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('admin',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not obj.pk:
            # Only set admin during the first save.
            obj.admin = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: it does not take the user who is active

Comment: @ЗуфарТангрибергенов can you add your view to the question?

Comment: I want to make sure that the administrator who logged into his account (there are several admins) filled in all the fields except the admin field. so that his nickname is automatically in the admin field and that this field is read only

Comment: мне нужно сделать в Rest API, not in admin panel

Comment: It doesn't work in admin for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I set serializers.HiddenField and by default set CurrentUserDefault() from serializers
automatically substitutes the value of the current admin and at the same time the admin field now goes to the api

```
class RegSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    admin = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Registration
        exclude = ['price', 'visit_date']
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly.